# How do I properly reference NETStandard 2.1?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I've seen comments stating that I will 'need Core 3.0' but I'm not sure what that means exactly.  Core 3.0 is installed on my system and I can create a Core 3.0 project if I want to but as far as I know I can't create a project that targets both Core 3.0 and .NET Standard 2.1.

Currently my project (class lib) target framework is .NET Standard 2.1.  It compiles fine but when I run the project (exe) that references it I get an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file 
specified.
```

The exe is a NET Framework 4.7 project. The reason that I need my dll to run under NET Standard is that it needs to be referenced in both NET Framework and Core projects.

Is there a trick to getting this to work properly?  Is there a different way to create a NET Standard 2.1 project?  Or are there dependency files that I need to copy locally?

Answer (score 1):

Had that issue when importing a net standart project from a net framework project. To fix put inside your `Web.config` the following, change my versions 4.7.1 and 2.0 to your needed ones:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1"/>
...
  </system.web>
```

Comment: My dll is not used in a web project so it does not have access to a web.config file.  It is referenced in both a Core ASP.NET project and a Windows service (exe).  The service is framework 4.7.  I tried something similar to what you have suggested is the csproj file to no avail..

Comment: Ddid you fix this @eric_the_animal